# I am not able to understand how recursion is happening in one particular case of divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, arrays

I have not understanding problem that uses divide & conquer paradigm: finding maximum subarray problem. Can some built a tree to exam me the recursion to make me understand what is happening in each a every recursive call and every step? In merge sort that use divide and conquer approach i understood that the array is first broken into the smallest subarrays. After the complete division we start merging from base to top step by step. But in this problem: `finding maximum subarray` i don't understand the combine step. If the array is divided then i has to be combined back. I am writing the algorithm first and i'll ask question using `\* *\` after the line of code as a comment.

IN THIS COMPLETE PROBLEM: the book says that 6 to 12 are the combine steps but i don't understand how this divided arrays are combined. Can someone make good drawing or photo to explain the complete process?

```
        Consider an array for this example, A = [-3,2,-1,3]

Find-Maximum-Subarray(A,low,high)
1) if high == low 
2)       return(low, high, A[low])
3) else mid = floor[(low+high)/2]
4)      (left-low,left-high,left-sum)= Find-Maximum-Subarray(A,low,mid)
```

/*This is a recursive call to Find-Maximum-Subarray so the program will not procede furthur it will keep on calling itself & last step will be  left-low will be signed the first index of array and the left-high will also be the first index and left-sum will be A[1] now i divides the furthur right subarray in next line of code */

```
5)      (right-low,right-high,right-sum)= Find-Maximum-Subarray(A,mid+1,high)
6)      (cross-low,cross-high,cross-sum)= Find-Max-Crossing-Array(A,low,mid,high)
7)      if left-sum >= right-sum and left-sum >= cross-sum
8)                return (left-low,left-high,left-sum)
9)      elseif right-sum >= left-sum and right-sum >= cross-sum
10)               return (right-low,right-high,right-sum)
11)     else 
12)               return (cross-low,cross-high,cross-sum)


Find-Max-Crossing-Array(A,low,mid,high)
1.1)left-sum = -infinity
1.2)sum=0
1.3)for i= mid downto low
1.4)     sum=sum+A[i] 
1.5)     if sum>left-sum
1.6)           left-sum = sum
1.7)           max-left= i 
1.8)right-sum= -infinity
1.9)sum =0
2.0)for j = mid+1 to high
2.1)     sum=sum+A[j]
2.2)     if sum>right-sum
2.3)           right-sum= sum
2.4)           max-right= j
2.5)return(max-left, max-right, left-sum+right-sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite recursion you're worried about doesn't happen, because before line 5 is reached line 1 has checked if you're down to a single index and returned an answer if so.

PS: There's a much simpler algorithm for the [maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). Just take the maximum of the partial sums iteratively clamped above zero: `array.Scan(0, (a, e) => Math.Max(0, a + e)).Max()`. To track the bounds you have to do a bit more book-keeping, though.

Comment: i know that there are easy alg. but might not take O(nlgn) time.

Comment: @StackOverflow The simpler algorithm is *linear* time. It's faster than the divide and conquer algorithm.